# JQuery year interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the data from localhost url. I have a variable called "DateRequest". I only want to take years between 1900 and 2030 for this variable. I wrote a code like this, but it does not work. How can I fix?

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#6e7b8b";

        $.get("http://localhost:8080/request",
               function (data, status) {
                   var year = {}
                   var yearrequestnum = [];

                   $.each(data, function (index, item) {

                       var girisYear = null;
                       if (item.DateRequest != null && item.DateRequest.length > 4)
                       {
                           girisYear = item.DateRequest.substr(0, 4);

                           if (yil[girisYear] == null) {
                               yil[girisYear] = 0;
                           }
                           yil[girisYear]++;
                       }
                   });
                   console.log(yil);

                   $.each(year, function (index, item) {
                       console.log(parseInt(index, 0));
                       if (parseInt(index, 0) < 1900 && parseInt(index, 0) > 2030)
                           return;
                       newitem = {}
                       newitem["girisYili"] = index
                       newitem["sayi"] = item;
                       yearrequestnum.push(newitem);
                   });

                   console.log(yearrequestnum)
```

```html
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
      <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the DateRequest in your code and what are you trying to loop through there? And your code is incomplete, syntax-wise

Comment: Please add your complete code.

Comment: Show us your year-Array

Comment: {"DateRequest":"2010-01-21",} Like this.